# resize images using % in css

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I am trying to create a liquid web layout using % for as many things as i can. I have hit a bump when resizing images.

both:

```
<img src="source" style="width: 20%; height: 20%;"/>
```

and

```
.wall_picture_block img{
width: 20%; 
height: 20%;
}
```

don't work properly with the height attribte. They resize the image width to 20% of the container but the height stays relative to the image size.(im trying to make squares)

Answer (score 6):

The percentages in `height` and `width` attributes of an image works with the container it is contained in. So to achieve the fluid effect just trying putting in a container around the img and give image height and width: `100%`. and now you should be changing the height and width of the container in percentages. Here's an example

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 100px;">
   <img src="your-image-link-here" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

With this your image will achieve a height and width of 500 * 100.

**UPDATE**

```
<div id="wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 900px; height: 400px;">
  <div id="imgcontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
     <img src="ur-img" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Example with a wrapper and the container with the percentages.

Comment: what if the container is a % of the wrapper?

Comment: yeah it will work. the container is a <div> and takes dimensions any which ways: %ages or pixels.

Comment: It works on helloworld with images from folder but not with images from db, it still makes em all different shapes. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you put up the part of the code that gets the images from db, may then I might be able to suggest a solution then. 
If I presume that you are just getting the image path from the database and putting it up in the 'src' attribute of the image then there should be no problem.

Comment: while($i < $rowNums){
 ?>
   
   <a href="getImages.php?ImageID= <?php echo mysql_result($rslt,$i,"ImageID"); ?>" rel="lightbox[all]"><img src="getImages.php?ImageID= <?php echo mysql_result($rslt,$i,"ImageID"); ?>"/></a>
   
 <?php
   $i++;

Comment: its all unformatted but essentially yeah, i use 2 files, one to get all ids and one to get the image based on the get thats sent to the file as src to get this: <a href="getImages.php?ImageID= 4" rel="lightbox[all]"><img src="getImages.php?ImageID= 4"/></a>

Answer (score 1):

You should crop the image. Once you use a % for width or height, I think the browser tries to preserve the aspect ratio, regardless of the value for the other dimension.

Comment: I tried using % for width/height, but my browser DOES NOT preserve the aspect ratio! (I am using Firefox 3.6) How can I change the above code so that images keep their aspect ratio? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image's width to be a percentage of its container, and for the image to maintain its original aspect ratio, define the width in percentage and set the height to auto:

```
.wall_picture_block img{
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is what he doesnt want Alex.

Comment: Oh i assumed that the original images were squares, but maybe that is not the case.