# 50% Width Responsive Design Issue

Tags: css, image, scroll, responsive-design

I'm searching for a way to be able to scroll in this page

http://bijusi01.businesscatalyst.com/shoes.html

I've been playing a bit with the css by adding some code in the header but the scrolling doesn't work (probably because of the position: fixed; but it's the only way I've found to make it responsive for now). Here is the code I added in the head :

```css
#u1760_img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 135px;
}
#u1765_img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    right: 0;
    text-align:right;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 135px;
}
```

Comment: You are WAY over-complicating things. Look, it's simple: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Pax/). The important thing to remember is that whitespace will screw up 50% width layouts, so make sure there are no spaces between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

### Scrolling Doesn't work:

Have you wondered why?

Because of this line of code:

```
position: fixed;
```

Why does this make scroll stop? Actually its not stoping the scroll, but instead the position of it is locked! The scoll is working, when you have a look at the scroll bar, but the image's position is fixed. You can use `position: absolute` to minimize this effect.

### 50% width for images:

When you use `50%` width for the images, you are actually letting the image have the 50% width of the **nearest parent element** with some width. For example:

```
  <div class="someclass">
    <img src="link/to/file.png" alt="photo" />
  </div>

.someclass {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Now when you set image with to `width: 50%;` it will fill 50% of the div; that's its parent. If you have not set any, then the body will be filled with 50%. And so on.

### The only issue that I found was:

The `position: fixed`. This was causing some issues, and one is nonscroll-ness, actually it is scroll, you can try giving a gradient background to the page, and when you'll scroll you'll see the changes!

### Make some changes in your CSS:

```
#u1760_img {
height: auto;
width: 50%;
float: right;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
top: 135px;
}
#u1765_img {
height: auto;
width: 50%;
float: left;
right: 0;
text-align:right;
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
z-index: 1;
top: 135px;
}
```

Instead of this, try using this:

```
img {
  width: 50%; // set the width
  position: absolute; // but still, its not the only way to position images
  top: 135px;
}
```

Note that I have not specified some CSS properties, why? `z-index` isn't necessary unless you have some elements which you want to overlap. So you won't require this one.

Secondly, I have not set height to auto, because browser will do that for us automatically :)

You are making a hell lot of other assumptions too, such as `text-align`, `float: left`, `right: 0;`. Try avoiding them in the beginning.

When you'll set image's width to 45%, the next image will come just infront of the first image so you won't have to write classes for each of them and the browser will automatically fit the images there for you!

### Not sure, but still have this too

I am not sure whether you want this or not, but still I am going to write for information.

You can use **media queries** to create dynamic pages that would work on mobiles, like a mobile version of your website. You can also try using `width: 50%` (which you actually are) to make the browser always fit the image in it when it is resized down.

### References:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

[resize images using % in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797395/resize-images-using-in-css)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index